# Bash: executing commands from within a chroot and switch user

Tags: linux, bash, unix, chroot

Im writing a script that should do this...

```
chroot /chroot_dir/ su -
./startup.sh (This should run within the su environment)
```

I have tried this approach:

```
chroot /chroot_dir /bin/bash -c " su -; ./startup.sh"
```

This tries to execute the user switching and the script as a string command to bash...however what it does, is it "stops" after
    **"su -"** and doesnt execute the script.
However, once I leave the "su -" environment, it does try to run startup.sh but of course, it cant find it.

Basically I need to nest the "startup.sh" to be run inside the "su -" environment...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

try

```
chroot /chroot_dir /bin/bash -c "su - -c ./startup.sh"
```

Comment: thanks so much, I dont know how I didnt see this in the man page!

Answer (score 31):

```
chroot /chroot_dir /bin/bash -x <<'EOF'
su -
./startup.sh
EOF
```

Comment: Nice syntax, this one.

Answer (score 9):

basic option:

```
cat << EOF | chroot /chroot_dir 
touch aaaaa
touch bbbbb
EOF
```

option with different shell (eg. if using bash but in chrooted enviroment it doesn't exists)

```
cat << EOF | chroot /chroot_dir /bin/sh
touch aaaaa
touch bbbbb
EOF
```